# Modifying App_code leads to session reset

Tags: asp.net

Whenever I update a file under App_Code folder the sessions on the site got recycled. (So everyone on the site loses their login)

I could not see anything about this in msdn.

So far I tried various sessionState options, compiling the class files and uploading dll files, no luck.

Any ideas, suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is probably by design.  Changes to those files force a recompile.  The temporaliy compiled files can be found in the ASP.NET Temporary folder under c:\windows\Microsoft.Net.  The recompile in turn is probably resulting in the AppDomain being reset.  The same is true with web.config changes, although it only recycles the AppDomain.

Answer (score 0):

I think You can do the following.

1. Use State Server for maintain the Session.
2. Use Cookie.
3. Use SQL Session Data.